Only big confusions: prove $f$ is discontinuous at $a \neq 0$
For the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
I'm stuck on proving $f$ is discontinuous at $a \neq 0$ with $a$ irrational or rational.
For the case $a \neq 0$ is rational I got stuck in the end because there is something wrong.
Since $a \neq 0$ is rational, I have $f(a) = 0$, hence
$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(x)| = |x|$$
Hence for some $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ I can fix some $\epsilon$ and notice that
$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |x| = |x + a - a| \leq |x - a| + |a| = \delta + |a|$$
But I want to show that I have not $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$. I don't know how to proceed.
For $a \neq 0$ irrational I met the same difficulties since in this case $f(a) = a$, and for $x$ rational I have
$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(a)| = |a|$$
Now for $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ I cannot find the ending for
$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |a| = |x - a + a| \leq |x-a|+|a| = \delta + |a|$$
Identical to the precedent.
Why isn't there a guide, or a general way to understand how to proceed for those exercises?
I'm too dumb, sorry and thank you for your help.
EDIT
What I also don't understand is this: in another solution I found, for the case $a$ is rational, reads:
be $a \neq 0$ and rational. Then $f(a) = 0$. Then
$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(x)|$$
Fix $\epsilon$, and $\delta$ be arbitrary. Then there does exist $x$ irrational such that $0 < |x-a| < \min\{\epsilon, \delta\}$ and we have
$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(x)| = |x| = |a - (a-x)| \geq |a| - |a - x| = |a| - \epsilon$$
From here we choose $\epsilon = \frac{|a|}{2}$. This shows $f$ is not continuous at $a \neq 0$ rational.
I don't understand why we chose $\min\{\epsilon, \delta\}$: shouldn't it be $0 < |x-a| < \delta$??
Also why do we have $|a-x| < \epsilon$ in the process? It was the min between $\epsilon, \delta$, so magically now it became $\epsilon$??
I cannot understand anything of this.
I just use a different inequality which apparently lead to nothing.

You have your epsilons and deltas the wrong way round. To show something is discontinuous at $a$, you'd want to explicitly produce some $\varepsilon$ where, given any $\delta>0$, there is an $x$ with $|f(x)-f(a)|<\delta$ but $|x-a|\geq\varepsilon$.

As for a guide, you should be able to find plenty online. Which textbooks are and are not effective will vary wildly depending on taste, but personally I thought Hart's Guide 2 Analysis explained things nicely; you can find other references online too.

@Lavender no. Your epsilons and deltas are wrong.

@Lavender What I don't understand is this: in another solution I found, for the case $a$ is rational, reads:
$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(x)| = |x| = |a - (a-x)| \geq |a| - |a - x| = |a| - \epsilon$$
since $0 < |x-a| < \min{\epsilon, \delta}$. From here we choose $\epsilon = \frac{|a|}{2}$. I don't understand why we chose $\min{\epsilon, \delta}$.
In my answer instead I wrote
$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(x)| = |x| = |x-a+a| \leq |x-a| + |a|$$
Why is my reasoning wrong? (Because it's wrong, it doesn't lead to a result). I just used a different inequality (see edit in the question)

For a simpler approach, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533237

@AnneBauval I cannot use sequences, only $\epsilon-\delta$.

@AnneBauval That is the "easy" way to understand, and I get this. But I do want to understand $\epsilon-\delta$, especially the confusions I read over here in another answer (see the edits). Nothing makes sense

The error in your solutions were not using the "definition" of discontinuity (which really is the negation of continuity) and using the standard triangle inequality instead of the reverse one.
To prove that it is discontinuous, you have to show there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$ there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|x - a| < \delta $ and $| f(x) - f(a) | \geq \epsilon$.
Pick $\epsilon_0 = \frac{|a|}{2}$ and let $\delta_0 > 0$. If $a$ is rational, then $f(a) = 0$, so for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$$|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(x)|$. Since the irrationals are dense in the reals, we can pick $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x_0 - a| < \min\{ \delta_0, \epsilon_0 \} $, also, $|a| > |a - x_0|$ holds since $\epsilon_0 = \frac{|a|}{2}$. We choose the minimum between both so that both $|x_0 - a| < \epsilon_0$ and $|x_0 -a | < \delta_0$ hold. Keep in mind that $-|x_0 - a| > -\min\{ \delta_0, \epsilon_0 \}$.  Using the reverse triangle inequality,
$$|f(x_0) - f(a) | = |f(x_0)| = |x_0| = | a - (a - x)| \geq |a| - |a - x_0|$$
Then
$$|f(x_0) - f(a)| \geq |a| - |x_0 - a| >  |a| - \epsilon_0 = |a| - \frac{|a|}{2} = \frac{|a|}{2} = \epsilon_0. $$
Now pick any $\epsilon_1 < |a|$ and let $\delta_1 > 0$. Now say $a$ is irrational, then $f(a) = a$, so for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $|f(x) - f(a)| = |f(x) - a|$. Since the rationals are dense in the reals, we can pick $x_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x_1 - a| < \delta_1 $ and .
$$|f(x_1)- f(a)| = |0-a| = |a| > \epsilon_1$$
Completing the proof.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Let $a\ne0$ (rational or irrational). $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not even exist, since
$$\lim_{x\to a\atop x\in\Bbb Q}f(x)=0\ne a=\lim_{x\to a\atop x\notin\Bbb Q}f(x).$$
This can be detailed with epsilon-delta: $\forall\epsilon>0$,

$\forall x\in\Bbb Q\quad|f(x)-0|=0<\epsilon$
$\forall x\in(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\setminus\Bbb Q\quad|f(x)-a|=|x-a|<\epsilon$.

Assume now (reasoning by contradiction) that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell$. Then, there exists $\delta>0$ (depending on $\epsilon$) such that

$\forall x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)\setminus\{a\}\quad|f(x)-\ell|<\epsilon$.

By density of $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, this, together with each of the two previous bullets, would entail (by triangular inequality):
$$|\ell-0|<2\epsilon\text{ and }|\ell-a|<2\epsilon.$$
(We derived $|\ell-0|<2\epsilon$ by choosing some rational number $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)\setminus\{a\}$, and writing $|\ell-0|\le|\ell-f(x)|+|f(x)-0|$. Similarly, we derived $|\ell-a|<2\epsilon$ by choosing some irrational number $x\in
(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\cap
(a-\delta,a+\delta)\setminus\{a\}$, and writing $|\ell-a|\le|\ell-f(x)|+|f(x)-a|$.)
Therefore, if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell$ then
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad|0-a|
\le
|0-\ell|+|\ell-a|
<4\epsilon.$$
Choosing some positive $\epsilon\le|a|/4$ leads to the desired contradiction.
Edit Alternatively, if you don't want to prove that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist, but only that it cannot be $f(a)$, just prove that (be $a$ rational or not)
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\ne a\text{ and }\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\ne0.$$
This can also be done by contradiction (which I usually prefer to avoid, but may seem here more "intuitive" than direct reasoning):

if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=a$ then, letting $\ell=a$ in our previous "$|\ell-0|<2\epsilon$": $$\forall\epsilon>0\quad|a|<2\epsilon$$
hence (taking the limit as $\epsilon\to0^+$)
$$|a|\le0$$
which contradicts $a\ne0$.
if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$, letting $\ell=0$ in our previous "$|\ell-a|<2\epsilon$", we get the same contradiction.


Honestly I have hard times in understanding this. Mathpunk proof was ways better and clearer, if not for that error, which another time again raised my level of confusion.

Why several times? You stated his proof had just one error... Anyway here I don't understand the reasoning. I mean I understood that you, at a certain point, started by reasoning via contradiction. Though before that you wrote the two bullets which if I read alone I would think the limit exist, since you provided the "$< \epsilon$".
I don't get also how you deduced $|\ell - 0| < 2\epsilon$ and the other part too (but if I get the first one, I'll get the second one).
Finally, I don't get the contradiction. Sigh

The two first bullets only prove that $\lim_{x\to a\atop x\in\Bbb Q}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to a\atop x\notin\Bbb Q}f(x)=a$, not that $ \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists.

Thank you for the edits. It's still unclear to me where does $|\ell -0|$ and $|\ell - a|$ come from. I mean why we consider them? From where they come?

The idea is that if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell$ exists, it has to be equal both to $\lim_{x\to a\atop x\in\Bbb Q}f(x)=0$ and to
$\lim_{x\to a\atop x\notin\Bbb Q}f(x)=a$, so both $|\ell -0|$ and $|\ell-a |$ should be $0$

Ok!!!! I think I got this. But I won't ever be able to do such exercises on my own

Never say never. Training makes things each time easier.

Thank you again. I really don't understand why there is NO book with such exercises and good deep theory. Other than MSE I couldn't find anything. Everyone is "calculate this calculate that" but no $\epsilon-\delta" proof is ever given. No such methods are well taught, nor in classes nor in notes. Exercises and examples are non existent as if professor do fear those exercises (and I can understand them). At a certain point the question is obvious: where on Earth have people like you learnt all this? :)

Try using sequential definition of continuity.
Let $(a\neq0)\in $R$  $. Let $(x_n)$ be sequence of in $Q$ such that $$lim(x_n) = a$$, such a sequence exist by density of $Q$ in $R$.
$$f(x_n) = 0, \forall \in N$$
Thus, $$lim f(x_n) = 0$$.
Now, let $(y_n)$ be sequence of in $R-Q$ such that $$lim(y_n) = a$$, such a sequence exist by density of irrational numbers in $R$.
$$f(y_n) = y_n, \forall \in N$$
Thus, $$lim f(y_n) = lim(y_n) = a \neq 0$$.
Since the limit of $f(x)$ doesn't exist at a, so $f(x)$ is discontinuous at a.

See OP's reply 12 hours ago to such a suggestion: (s)he "cannot use sequences, only ϵ−δ".
